# CLion does not find standard headers & therefore does not show hints for structs or methods

Tags: autocomplete, clion

I'm running CLion 2016.1.3 on a Gentoo Linux Operating System with Gnome Desktop Environment.

For some strange reason the application (default settings) does not show me

1. the existing members of a struct
2. method signatures

from external headers while typing.

It is working for structures or methods that are declared in headers within my project structure, but not for standard headers located in /usr/include or other external libraries.

When adding preprocessor directives like #include, the program usually shows a small dropdown (on the Mac OS X) where I can simply choose the header from a list. This is also not working wit my Linux version and external headers. It is working fine again with Headers within my project structure / same directory.

Does anyone know if i miss some setting or something? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 3):

For the record. CLion still does not support Autotools, I found a solution by using a dummy CMakeLists.txt then use the "Reload CMake Project" Button. That imports the standard headers to the "External Libraries" section and autocompletion is working again.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(dummy)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES <path to any .c file in the project>)
add_executable(dummy ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build your project first, it seems to initialize all the indexing during the build